# CSS div height too short headache

Tags: css, html, height, footer, stretch

I have a div (id="main") that is not stretching to accommodate the dynamically created (i.e. height-variable) content inside of it; the 'main' div is only coming down to the bottom of 'user-info'.

The basic structural layout of this page is that the 'user-info' and 'stream' divs sit next to each other inside of the 'main' div which sits inside of 'container'; the 'meal-category-box' divs are just lists of content inside 'stream'. Here's the HTML and CSS (I am also using Bootstrap CSS 2).

http://jsfiddle.net/7yvSj/1/

I'd also love a sticky footer fix, because none of the ones I've looked at integrate with what I've got.

Please help!
Matt

Comment: @Pankaj That's two copies and pastes... http://jsfiddle.net/7yvSj/1/

Comment: @MrLister and the jsfiddle done :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since #stream has `position:absolute`, it doesn't partake in the calculation of the outer div's height.

Try to do something with paddings or margins instead of using `position:absolute`.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. I now have a different problem, but such is the way with CSS ironing!